# get subsection of a textfile using awk, sed or grep

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I'm afraid I'm not an expert at any of the three tools listed, so I'm asking you all.

I have a large text file that can be broken into multiple sections, each of which has the header `ABC` and the footer `&&`. A typical file would look like this:

```
ABC

...

<ID>
123

...

&&

ABC

...

<ID>
124

...

&&
```

I need to retrieve a section based on a given `ID`, for example if the `ID=123`, I would like the output to be:

```
ABC

<ID>
123

&&
```

Where there is random data between `ABC` `<ID>`, and between `123` and `&&`. The actual `ID`, `123`, is variable.

I believe that doing `awk '/ABC/,/\&\&/'` works in finding each subsection, but I don't know how to get the subsection corresponding to the correct ID. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit:** Clarified the question and the sample input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
id=123
sed '/^ABC/,/^&&/{/^ABC/{h;d};H;/^&&/!d;g;/<ID>\n'"$id"'/p};d' file
```

An alternative method:

```
sed ':a;$bb;N;/^ABC/!D;/&&$/!ba;:b;/^ABC.*<ID>\n'"$id"'.*&&$/p;d' file
```

Comment: Similar to @slitvinov 's solution, yours works well if there's only one section within a text file that starts with `ABC` and ends with `&&`. A typical text file will have multiple sections, however, each with a different ID.

Comment: @Alex this should retrieve just the section containing the input id, regardless of multiple sections.

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that your input file consists exclusively of `ABC ... <ID> ... &&` sections, possibly separated by blank lines.

**USAGE:** `awk -f foo.awk ID=123 input_file`

**foo.awk:**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    RS = "\n&&\n";
    ORS = RS;
}

match($0, "<ID>\n" ID "\n") {
    sub(/^\n/,"",$0);
    print $0;
}
```

If `/usr/bin/awk` matches your awk and you make foo.awk executable you can call it directly: `./foo.awk ID=123 input_file`

This code splits your input into records on each `&&` on a single line.
Then it searches the record for

```
<ID>
your_id
```

and prints it if it finds a match.

`sub(/^\n/,"",$0);` just eliminates blank lines between sections.

You can also have this on one line:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{ID=124;RS="\n&&\n";ORS=RS};match($0, "<ID>\n" ID "\n") {sub(/^\n/,"",$0);print $0;}' input_file
```

Comment: Cool solution! I would make it more idiomatic and add regexp to deal with `<ID>\n123\n&&`: `BEGIN {
    ORS=RS="\n&&\n"
}

match($0, "<ID>\n" ID "(\n|$)") {
    gsub(/^\n/,"")
    print
}`

Answer (score 0):

In sed you can do so:

```
sed -i ' /ABC/,/&&/ !{d} ' FILE
```

This will keep all context between ABC and &&.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. My intention is to _retrieve_ a subsection with the header `ABC` and footer `&&` and the proper ID, rather than inserting the ID line. Each subsection of the text file has a different ID.

Answer (score 0):

Usage: `awk -v id=123 -f foo.awk foo.txt`

**foo.awk**

```
$0=="ABC",$0=="&&"{
    # store everything in data
    # ternary operation to avoid leading "\n"
    data=data?(data "\n" $0):$0
}


id_flag {
    # this is a string after "<ID>"
    if (id==$1) { 
       print_flag = 1
    }
    id_flag = 0
}

$0=="<ID>"{
    # prepare to read id
    id_flag = 1
}

$0=="&&"{
    if (print_flag) {
      print data
      print_flag = 0
    }
    data = ""
}
```

Comment: I think my question was a bit vague. An average text file I have will have multiple sections that each start with `ABC` and end with `$$$$`. I believe this solution only works for a text file with a single section as described.